# How to validate array in json response?

Tags: arrays, json, testing, postman, assertion

Greatings,

I was wondering how to validate an array with postman

I have this answer:

```
{
"documents": [
            {
                "documentType": "FORM",
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "kind": {
                            "code": "COMPANY",
                            "name": "Company name"
                        },
                        "value": "KKO",
                        "confidence": 0.0
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": {
                            "code": "AGREEMENT",
                            "name": "Agreement number"
                        },
                        "value": "123",
                        "confidence": 0.0
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": {
                            "code": "DATE_OF_ISSUE",
                            "name": "When it was created"
                        },
                        "value": "01/01/2019",
                        "confidence": 0.0
                    }
}
```

I want to validate the second attribute which is:

```
{
                        "kind": {
                            "code": "AGREEMENT",
                            "name": "Agreement number"
                        },
```

Including `value` field

```
                        "value": "123",
                        "confidence": 0.0
                    },
```

I was wondering what will be the easiest way to validate this?

I've tried to write paths like:

```
const response = pm.response.json()

attribute1 = response.data.documents[0];
attribute2 = response.data.documents[1];
attribute3 = response.data.documents[3];

pm.expect(attributes[1].kind.code).to.equal("AGREEMENT");

pm.expect(attributes[1].kind.name).to.equal("Agreement number");
```

but it is all too heavy and time consuming.

I would much appreciate if you share with me your experience and provide the clue on how to resolve my issue.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pm.expect([1,2,3,4,5]).to.deep.equal([1,2,3,4,5])
```

or

```
pm.expect(_.isEqual([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5])).to.be.true
```

so in your case:

```
  pm.expect([
    {
        "kind": {
            "code": "COMPANY",
            "name": "Company name"
        },
        "value": "KKO",
        "confidence": 0.0
    },
    {
        "kind": {
            "code": "AGREEMENT",
            "name": "Agreement number"
        },
        "value": "123",
        "confidence": 0.0
    },
    {
        "kind": {
            "code": "DATE_OF_ISSUE",
            "name": "When it was created"
        },
        "value": "01/01/2019",
        "confidence": 0.0
    }]).to.deep.equal([
                    {
                        "kind": {
                            "code": "COMPANY",
                            "name": "Company name"
                        },
                        "value": "KKO",
                        "confidence": 0.0
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": {
                            "code": "AGREEMENT",
                            "name": "Agreement number"
                        },
                        "value": "123",
                        "confidence": 0.0
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": {
                            "code": "DATE_OF_ISSUE",
                            "name": "When it was created"
                        },
                        "value": "01/01/2019",
                        "confidence": 0.0
                    }])
```

**Update**

```
name = ["Company name", "Agreement number", "When it was created"]
value = ["KKO", "123", "01/01/2019"]

pm.test("something", function () {
    a.forEach((a, i) => {
        pm.expect(a.kind.name).to.be.equal(name[i])

        pm.expect(a.value).to.be.equal(value[i])
    })
})
```

Comment: Hello PDHide, I'm afraid I don't quite get the resolve

Comment: I only wanted to validate the second attribute's code, name and value.

Comment: added the answer use same logic , assuming a to be the attribute array

Comment: Can you tell me please... what if I have a duplicate in 'name' field ?

Comment: Array can have duplicate values

Comment: And I will have to enumerate them all in the name field right ?

Comment: forEach returns the index also so name[i] will call the expected output in order

Comment: That is not going to work for me, cuz my response body is longer than just 3 or 4 name field values. I have something like 20 or 30 and enumerating them all will take a huge amount of time unfortunately. Can there be another way ?

Comment: It won't take huge amount of time to enumerate 20 fields ! .

Comment: However, can you provide me with the solution on how to validate only the second attribute fields 'name', 'code' and 'value' without too much writing ?\